# Update table entry: Spring Form

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have a table called Students. I need to develop a page like Student Profile. For example let's say Student name and Address is there.

I need to display current details of the Student in a form (which I can do). Then I need to allow the user to edit current name or address. So user can edit some field and click submit.

Basically to update certain values of table I need to write a update query. Since what I get at controller is a POJO containing submitted form values. I am wondering whether there is a proper pattern to do this. I have following questions

- How to identify fields with updated values
- How to dynamically create the query to update only that fileds in the table

What I need is a design pattern like explanation.

Comment: Don't write queries use an ORM like hibernate to figure that out for you. So the design pattern would be use ORM...

Comment: I'm going with Spring JDBC for the moment. In that case?

Comment: Keep it simple, why do you need a dynamic query? Simply create a query that updates all fields. But still I strongly advice against it and use Hibernate (or whatever ORM tool you select). Almost no-one writes its own JDBC code anymore (unless in special circumstances, like massive complex reporting queries etc.).

Comment: Do I need to compare object submitted by form and original table record to identify edited fields and write a update query or is there a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should create separate object only for those fields which you need to update.